# Configuration.SaveAs writes empty config

Tags: c#, .net

Getting some odd behavior from Configuration class. This code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var configFile = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
        var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);
        var value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Supercali"];
        if (value != null) Console.WriteLine("Yay, it finally worked!");
        else Console.WriteLine("Still broken.");
        configuration.SaveAs("ReadConfig.config");
    }
}
```

with this config in `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Supercali" value="Fragalistic"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

writes the following to "ReadConfig.config"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

and prints this

> Still broken.

Looking at it in debug view, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile` has the correct file, but `OpenExeConfiguration` seems to create a blank config. The `appSettings` section is empty. I'm pretty sure this is wrong, but maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
        var configFile = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
        var configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(configFile);
        var value = configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Supercali"];
        if (value != null) Console.WriteLine("Yay, it finally worked!");
        else Console.WriteLine("Still broken.");
        configuration.SaveAs("ReadConfig.config");
```

The `OpenExeConfiguration` expects the path to a DLL/EXE, *not* to the `.config` file.

Comment: Doh, that was it! Thanks!